# User defined function in R is not working

Tags: r

I am trying to run below code in R but it's not working. Need your help. Let me explain my requirement.
I have data frame named `Data`. In that I have column called `view`. Let's consider `view` contains 6 values `1,2,3,5,20,NA`.
Now I want to calculate 99 percentile on view. Using quantile function on this data will give me quantile value 19 (rounded off).
Now I am checking condition if view column having any value greater than 19, replace it with 19. Here in our example, we have one value greater than 19 which is 20, so 20 should be replace with 19.

Now, if I run all the code manually like below it works fine

```
Data <- data.frame(view=c(1,2,3,5,20,NA))

summary(Data)
n = quantile(Data$view, 0.99, na.rm = TRUE)

Data$view[Data$view > n] <- n
```

But I want to create a function which can just call variable from data frame and do the above job. Below is the function  I tried, but not working.

```
ReplaceQuantile <- function(x) {
  n = quantile(na.omit(x),0.99)
  x[x > n] <- n
}

ReplaceQuantile (Data$view)
```

Hope now my requirement is clear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Do you just want to do this for selected columns or all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost working. I recommend to use `na.rm = TRUE` in your quantile function instead of `na.omit`:

```
ReplaceQuantile <- function(x) {
  n = quantile(x, 0.99, na.rm = TRUE)
  x[x > n] <- n
  x
}

ReplaceQuantile (Data$view)
```

This way you remove `NA` and your function should run.

EDIT: Consider this reproducible example:

```
Data <- data.frame(view = c(seq(1, 5, by = .1), NA))

ReplaceQuantile <- function(x) {
   n = quantile(x, 0.99, na.rm = TRUE)
   x[x > n] <- n
   x
}

ReplaceQuantile(Data$view)
```

EDIT II for clarification: You need to assign the result to `Data$view` in order to overwrite the original values:

```
Data <- data.frame(view=c(1,2,3,5,20,NA))

ReplaceQuantile <- function(x) {
   n = quantile(x, 0.99, na.rm = TRUE)
   x[x > n] <- n
   x
  }

 Data$view <- ReplaceQuantile(Data$view)
```

This way you should get the following results:

```
 Data$view
 [1]  1.0  2.0  3.0  5.0 19.4   NA
```

Comment: Hi, I did the same as suggested but later if I check summary of Data$view, seems values are not getting replaced with quantile value in data frame

Comment: You are right! My bad but are you replacing the result of your function into `Data$view` like this: `Data$view <- ReplaceQuantile(Data$view)`

Comment: @BenNutzer You have to return the value of `x`. I have edited the function with just `x` as the last code line. Oh, upvoted the `na.rm` idea, it's much better than `na.omit`.

Comment: In function, I have this line "x[x > n] <- n" so wherever Data$view is greater than n I want to replace it with n. Seems this "x[x > n] <- n" is not working in function

Comment: @kushalchawda I added a minimal working example. Does that help? If not please give us another example that might be closer to your own data.

Comment: Please check. I have edited my question with requirement

Comment: @kushalchawda You must assign the return value of the function back to the column. What functions do inside them is lost on return. Do what is in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466089/user-defined-function-in-r-is-not-working/53466191#comment93803284_53466191).

Comment: Hi that way it's replacing all the column value with 19, I just want to replace value 20 with 19. rest values of column should remain as it is

Comment: @kushalchawda I recommend to restart your session and to run the snippet again. You should get the desired results as displayed in my answer.

Comment: Yes. After restarting R studio it works now. But what kind of issue is this?

Comment: @kushalchawda Hard to say but I assume your `Data$view` values had been already overwritten by one of your earlier attempts and therefore had the value of `19.4` for every observation.